# Unable to see View in TOAD, but can see in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I am using TOAD for Oracle version 11.0.5.1. I am able to see a View in an Oracle schema when I login using Oracle SQL Developer. But, **when using TOAD, I am NOT able to access the View or see any data in it**. For another View, I can access the View, but it doesn't return any data. I am able to access other DB objects though. Any idea why I can see via Oracle SQL Developer and not via TOAD in the same PC, same database, same schema?

I also tried in another system (PC) where TOAD 12.6.053 is installed, and I was able to access the views, and see data when I query it.

Not sure if there is any session or NLS parameters that might be causing this. Please help.

P.S. - This view that I am trying to access is in another schema, but I have access to query the view. Hence, I am able to access and see the data through Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: If you are logged as another user which is not an owner of this schema, then use `SELECT * FROM schema_name.view_name`. If this does not work, then the current user does not have permissions to this view, you must grant him persissions - login as `view_owner_user` and use `GRANT SELECT ON view_name TO another_user_name`

Comment: Yes, I am logged in with my account, and I am trying to access the same way you mentioned. (schema_name.view_name). I already have select access on the view. I can query from another system or SQL Developer, but not from TOAD :(

Comment: Could be that the privilege is not granted directly to the user, but throuht a role. In such a case use `SET ROLE rolename` to enable the role for the current session in TOAD.

Comment: What error do you get for the view you can’t access at all? For the other one, is the view query perhaps doing an implicit conversion that is being affected by NLS settings? (Are you really sure you are actually hitting the same database - how are you connecting in each case?)